# CakePHP Paginator: get first item from next page?

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination, cakephp-4.x

I have a table that contains different versions of a text. I want to display the diffs of each version with the previous version. I also want to paginate through the versions, in case there are more than 20. However, to diff the last text on each page I would need the first text of the next page. I cannot just make the page size one larger (21 in this case), because the second page would skip its first entity, and the third its first two etc.

```php
$config = $this->Paginator->getConfig();
$this->Paginator->setConfig('limit', $config['limit'] + 1);
$inscriptions = $this->paginate($query);
```

I might instead be able to solve the problem by making a separate `->paginate()` call for the single entity, but I would rather not execute a second query if possible.

```php
$inscriptions = $this->paginate($query);

$config = $this->Paginator->getConfig();
$this->Paginator->setConfig([
    'limit' => 1,
    'page' => ($config['page'] * $config['limit']) + 1
]);
$inscriptions[] = $this->paginate($query)->first();
```

Is there a way to skip the first n results? In that case I *could* set the page size to 21 but set the page number to 1, and skip the first ((old page number - 1) * old page size) entities.

Comment: Have you checked what the `page` function does internally?

Comment: @GregSchmidt Yes, it passes page and limit through as-is to the Query class. From there it seems to get converted to offset+limit. I have tried, but cannot overwrite the offset by passing it as well (the option gets passed through but isn't applied). Bypassing the paginator like that might also mess with the pages in the view element, so I might try to write my own PaginatorInterface I guess.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to make a custom paginator that extends the default one, but functions as described:

```php
<?php
namespace App\Datasource;

use Cake\Core\InstanceConfigTrait;
use Cake\Datasource\Paginator;
use Cake\Datasource\QueryInterface;
use Cake\Datasource\RepositoryInterface;

class DiffPaginator extends Paginator
{
    use InstanceConfigTrait;

    protected function getQuery(RepositoryInterface $object, ?QueryInterface $query = null, array $data): QueryInterface
    {
        $data['options']['offset'] = ($data['options']['page'] - 1) * $data['options']['limit'];
        $data['options']['limit'] += 1;
        unset($data['options']['page']);

        return parent::getQuery($object, $query, $data);
    }

    protected function buildParams(array $data): array
    {
        $paging = parent::buildParams($data);
        if ($paging['current'] == $paging['perPage'] + 1) {
            $paging['current'] -= 1;
        }
        return $paging;
    }
}
```

In your controller then use the following:

```php
$this->Paginator->setPaginator(new DiffPaginator);
```